# Restore local files deleted by Git

Tags: git, ubuntu, restore

I had a local folder containing my project, consisting out of multiple subfolders which was supposed to be added to a repository of my organizations GitLab Server (which only contains a readme and a gitignore specifiing all subfolders except /.../src/).  However, after setting up git to the local folder and executing the following commands:

```
git init
git checkout BRANCH_NAME
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git push -u origin BRANCH_NAME
```

my local folder is basically gone. All Folders specified in the gitignore are complete deleted, the src folder still exists, however is empty as well (contained a .cpp file before). I did not use any type of force or rm so I am quite suprised my local files are gone (they did not upload to the repository as well).

Any way to fix this and not be fucked tomorrow when going to work? All help I could find was directed towards restoring files from the repo, but since that one is empty as well when looking at it on the website I am quite helpless as to what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They are just gone.

Comment: No, but first... language... Anyway, the commands you've posted wouldn't have deleted your files so obviously you would need to have done something else or more than just those commands.  I can say that with certainty because first and foremost, the `git checkout` command you've posted would've complained with "error: pathspec 'BRANCH_NAME' did not match any file(s) known to git", and secondly you have not added a remote so that push would've failed as well. So obviously those commands are not what you used. Please go back and try to remember exactly what you did.

Comment: Not enough context. `git checkout BRANCH_NAME` will not work on newly inited repositories. You didn't tell exactly what did you do.

Comment: Sorry about the language. You are right, I used more commands than this. The repository existed before, wasn't created by me, just tried to fill it with life. All commands listed (and probably some very wrong in the context ... forgive me):

    cd PATH_TO_FOLDER
    git init
    git remote add origin URL
    git add *
    git commit -m "init"
    git push -u origin BRANCH (led to an error)
    git pull
    git checkout BRANCH

Comment: `git checkout BRANCH` restored working copy to whatever was (is) in that BRANCH. So, if you have your repo still untouched after what happened, try to run `git reflog` and see what changes had been done lately.

Comment: could you post what your branches look like? git log --oneline --graph --decorate=short --all.  This may give others the needed info to help.